# Vuejs2 firebase execute a function when data changes fails

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2

I have added vuefire and firebase

```
 "vuefire": "^1.4.5",
 "firebase": "^5.8.5",
```

IN my configuration i have

```
 var config = {
     //from  firebase
  }
Vue.use(VueFire);
Vue.prototype.$firebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

What am trying to achieve is to execute a function whenever data changes on a node registered. SO im my component i have added

```
mounted(){
     this.$firebase.database().ref('registered').on('value', function(snapshot) {
           console.log("there is a new change here");
     });
}
```

But the above never executes the console.log even when i change the data in my firebase realtime database.
What am i missing

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use vuefire? Why not just use the Firebase SDK for javacript (https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)? You can then just do something like this in your `mounted()` function: `firebase.database().ref('registered').on('value',function(snapshot)...`

Comment: even by removing use of vuefire still my code fails

Comment: Does it throw any error? Is your firebase configuration correct?

Comment: No errors thrown but simply doesnt log to the console. I decided to use firestore instead of database which works